# How to script to check the maximum number of textures supported per shader?

Tags: python, scripting, shaders, image

I ask this, because I would like to create a python script that checks what is the maximum number of Textures supported for Shader.
This would prove very useful in understanding how many different textures are supported for a single material.

I am currently aware of limitations (Maybe 8) on Macintosh systems, and on Windows systems, this limit should be 24 textures (At least, on my computer)
I'd like to figure out how to actually check this limit with a script.

I also based my question because of this known problem reported here at this link:
https://developer.blender.org/T66590

I would like to understand how and if it is possible to build a function that gives as a result the limit of Texture Slots Available at most per Shader

Comment: I don't think you can.  The problem is in OpenGL and the necessary information isn't exported from OpenGL to blender's Python bpy interface.  You'll probably have to write a separate program that opens the ogl library and queries it.  But I'm not even sure ogl provides the necessary info directly.

Comment: At this point, it would be interesting to see if there is a python library that gives such information.

Answer (score 6):

[This answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/30101) from gamedev explains that

> The number of textures that can be bound to OpenGL is not [...] GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS

but rather is the maximum number of texture units provided by your graphics hardware.  OpenGL requires this number to be 16 or larger and older hardware typically has a value of 32; but there is no guarantee of the value for a particular card.

Blender does expose a partial [interface to OpenGL](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bgl.html) and you can find the absolute maximum value:

```
import bgl
print(bgl.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS)
```

but Blender does not support a means of querying the hardware to determine the characteristics of your graphics card.